# How to use react-native-camera for realtime pose detection?

Tags: typescript, react-native, tensorflow

I have been trying to use react-native camera to capture an image. This image is given as input into a posenet-model. The detected pose is supposed to be drawn on the canvas.

```
const takePicture = async () => {
    if (cameraRef !== null) {
        const options = {quality: 0.5, base64: true}
        const data = await cameraRef.current!.takePictureAsync(options)

    }
}
takePicture()

return (
    <View style={screenStyle}>
        <RNCamera
            ref={cameraRef}
            style={cameraStyle as ViewStyle}
            type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
            flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto}
        />
        <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={takePicture} >
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
);
```

I wanted to know if there is a better way of using the camera to extract frames and process it into the model. Can you help me figure out the logic behind this.

Thank You